# Kotlin create email client (javamail, Google OAUTH, kotlin) - AUTHENTICATIONFAILED invalid credentials (failure)

Tags: kotlin, jakarta-mail, gmail-api, email-client

I'm trying to develop a small android email client in kotlin.
I use javanais api and google OAUTH but I got the following message.

> -----TEST START----- 
> -----TEST BP1-----
> -----TEST BP2-----
> ERROR:javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
> ERROR MESSAGE : [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
> ERROR MESSAGE : kotlin.Unit

The retrieval of the google oauth token works well but not the passing it to javanais api.

MainActivity.kt :

```
package fr.nothing.lab.emailtest

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient? = null
    private val RC_SIGN_IN = 9001

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

    }

    public override fun onStart(){
        super.onStart()
        val mGmailSignIn = findViewById<SignInButton>(R.id.sign_in_button)
        val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
        Log.w("MainActivity--Sign in 1:", account.toString())
        mGmailSignIn.setOnClickListener {
            signIn()
        }

    }
    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            handleSignInResult(task)
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>){
        Log.w("MainActivity -- Sign in 2:", completedTask.toString())
        try{
            val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            val idToken = getString(R.string.server_client_id)
            val email = account!!.email
            val ee = account!!.isExpired
            Log.w("MainActivity -- Sign in 4 :","Token id :"+idToken.toString() + " | "+email)
            Log.w("MainActivity -- Sign in 4 :","email :"+email)
            Log.w("MainActivity -- Sign in 4 :","expried :"+ee)
            if(idToken != null){
                val pop3Host = "imap.gmail.com"
                val mailStoreType = "imaps"
                val username = email.toString()
                val password = idToken

                val tp = threadperso(true,pop3Host, mailStoreType, username, password)
                tp.start()


            }

        }catch(e: ApiException){
            Log.w("MainActivity--Sign in 3:","signInResult:failed open =" + e.statusCode)
        }
    }

    private fun signIn(){
        val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient!!.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)

    }
}
```

thradperso.kt

```
package fr.nothing.lab.emailtest

import android.os.AsyncTask

class threadperso(
    private val google : Boolean,
    private val pop3Host : String,
    private val storeType  : String,
    private val user : String,
    private val password : String

) : Thread(){

    public override fun run(){
        ReceiveEmail.receiveEmail(google, pop3Host, storeType, user, password)
    }
}
```

ReceiveEmail.kt

```
package fr.nothing.lab.emailtest

import android.util.Log
import java.util.*
import javax.mail.Address
import javax.mail.Folder
import javax.mail.Message
import javax.mail.Session

class ReceiveEmail {
    companion object{
        fun receiveEmail(
            google : Boolean,
            pop3Host : String,
            storeType  : String,
            user : String,
            password : String
        ){
            val TAG = "MainActivity"
            var prop = Properties()
            //prop.put("mail.imaps.host", pop3Host)
            //prop.put("mail.imaps.port","993")
            //prop.put("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory")
            prop.put("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true")
            prop.put("mail.imaps.auth", "true")
            prop.put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable","true")
            prop.put("mail.imaps.ssl.trust","*")
            prop.put("mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms","XOAUTH2")
            prop.put("mail.store.protocol","imaps")
            var session = Session.getInstance(prop)
            Log.w(TAG,"-----TEST START-----")
            try {
                Log.w(TAG,"-----TEST BP1-----")
                //var mailStore = session.getStore(storeType)
                var mailStore = session.getStore(storeType)
                Log.w(TAG,"-----TEST BP2-----")
                mailStore.connect(pop3Host, 993, user, password.toString())
                Log.w(TAG,"-----TEST BP3-----")
                var folder : Folder = mailStore.getFolder("INBOX")
                Log.w(TAG,"-----TEST BP4-----")
                folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY)
                Log.w(TAG,"-----TEST BP5-----")
                var emailMessage = folder.getMessages()
                Log.w(TAG,"Total Message - " + emailMessage.size)
                var i = 1
                for(mess : Message in emailMessage){

                    var toAddSize : Int = mess.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO).size
                    var toAdress = mess.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)
                    Log.w(TAG,"-----TEST BP6-----")
                    Log.w(TAG,"EMAIL : "+ i.toString() + "/"+emailMessage+1)

                    Log.w(TAG,"Subject : "+ mess.subject)
                    Log.w(TAG,"From : "+mess.from[0])
                }

                folder.close()
                mailStore.close()
            }catch(e : Exception ){
                Log.w(TAG, "ERROR:"+e.toString())
                Log.w(TAG, "ERROR MESSAGE : " + e.message.toString())
                Log.w(TAG, "ERROR MESSAGE : " + e.printStackTrace())


            }



        }
    }

}
```